# Is there a software that can change my videos into just audio?

Tags: video, audio

I  have a youtube downloader, and it downloads videos incredibly well. Amazing quality, names them properly, and its fast. It even does playlist's. The downfall is if you just want the audio you need to pay for it.
I'm wondering if there is a software that can rip the audio into mp3 from a whole bunch of videos?

Comment: Those videos have both video and audio streams, so you don't need to change anything, you just need to separate the streams and copy the audio out. Have a look here: http://www.guidingtech.com/5729/13-free-software-rip-audio-from-video/

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Comment: This is all on windows 7. 
Thanks for that link MaQleod!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ffmpeg can convert many file types. Usually I just have to run this command (in a terminal/command prompt, depending on what OS you use):

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT_FILE OUTPUT_FILE.mp3
```

If you're not choosy about the output quality, this should do it for you. (I'm not choosy, knowing nothing about audio quality, so it works for me.)

On Linux, ffmpeg can be installed from your package manager. On Mac OS X, I have installed it via MacPorts. I've also installed it on Windows; I don't remember where, but it's ultimately linked from the ffmpeg homepage.

Comment: I'm running windows 7. What if I would like high quality, will this strip the audio in that sort of quality?

Comment: Good call on ffmpeg, Winff can also make it easy to get around some of the command line switches http://winff.org

Comment: @Robsta, I don't know what audio quality will be like. I believe ffmpeg can do high quality, but you will have to learn that from someone other than I. I just use it to convert OGGs (mainly from Wikipedia) into MP3s for iTunes.

Comment: Uhmm. okay. Thank you. I'll dig into it with this method. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are on OS X, the new Lion version of QuickTime can strip audio from video.

Comment: Not OS X, windows 7. But I can now see a reason why I might want a mac :P

Comment: Might want to look into the Windows version. It may or may not have it.

Comment: okay, i'll check that.

Comment: Could you explain how to strip the audio (in your answer)

Comment: @Simon I wish I could, but I haven't even looked at the feature. I literally heard about it a couple days prior to that. Anyone else can feel free to update it if they find the feature.

Answer (score 0):

I had some success with http://www.listentoyoutube.com/ but googling for "youtube mp3" returns many results.

Comment: Could you provide a link of some examples?

Comment: Well I have a good youtube downloader. I love how it works, and I want to keep using that to download the videos. Considering the speed and how much it can download at once is outstanding. It's called youtube downloader and I quite enjoy it. I just need to be able to strip the audio from the video's after. That's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The free, web-based service [Zamzar](http://www.zamzar.com/) will do video > audio conversions.

Comment: Yeah, I don't need a web based service. The downloader I got that downloads videos is quite fast. Downloads in HQ and it can download whole playlist's at once. 
I just need to strip the audio from all the downloaded songs.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this [YouTube downloader](http://www.youtubetoipod.biz/best-youtube-converter.html), I know it can help you download youtube video to computer for free. You can also use it to extract the audio from YouTube video as MP3 songs.

Comment: Yes. Thats what I'm using, the youtube downloader. But you have to pay for the pro version that can rip the audio.

Answer (score -1):

Try Handbrake. It combines the FOSS tools like ffmpeg into nice multi-platform GUI package, and can do pretty much any conversion, including separating audio and video tracks.

Comment: Does it strip the audio in HQ? 
Other than that it looks good. :D